# Running PIC18F2580 at +3.3v .. Are there any consequences?

Tags: pic

I’m looking to change my design in terms of powering my PIC18F2580 (IC3 on my schematic below) from my MCP1703 +3.3v voltage regulator (IC2 on my schematic below) - [see datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22049e.pdf).

[image: See my schematic screenshot below.]

Currently I’m supplying power to my PIC18F2580 from my +5V LM7805 (IC1 on my schematic above). Based on my understanding of the “Absolute Maximum Ratings” PIC18F2580 datasheet ([see page 416 of the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39637b.pdf)) it is possible to run the PIC at +3.3V i.e. **Voltage on VDD with respect to VSS ......................................................................................................... -0.3V to +7.5V**.

The reason for the change is due to the feedback received from my board house whereby they mention by having two different supply voltages on my board I could have “unknown long term consequences”.

What could these be? Could having two different supply voltages cause a problem with my Tx Rx interfacing between my ETRX357HR Zigbee module(IC7 on my schematic above)  and my PIC18F2580.

As for the MCP1703 if I were to change my design this would mean directly providing the MCP1703 with incoming +12v supply voltage from my PSU which would be OK based on the MCP1703  “Absolute Maximum Ratings”.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
TokTok.

Comment: No, its possible o apply 3.3V to the power pins, without damaging it, though.  That's what Absolute Maximum Ratingsx tell you --- anf that's ALL they tell you.

Comment: I wouldn't change anything. The board house is in no position to tell you how many supply rails to have on your board. Their job is to make what you send them.

Comment: This is a dumb question since it's directly and clearly answered in the datasheet right where you'd expect to find it.  See figure 28-2 on page 422 of DS39637D.

Answer (score 2):

You might get lucky but it probably won't run at the highest clock speed. Using the absolute maximum ratings doesn't tell you anything about operational behavior - they are telling you this information so you don't destroy the device with over-voltage or over-current.

If you want to run it at supplies below 4.2 volts use the 18LF version.

> The reason for the change is due to the feedback received from my
>   board house whereby they mention by having two different supply
>   voltages on my board I could have “unknown long term consequences”.

That is a bizarre thing to say. I've designed plenty of boards with all manner of different supply voltages and have no worries about that at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed as the PIC not running at the highest clock speed is not one reason I would have thought of. And I agree with you regarding the board house feedback I got. On a breadboard I've been working on a proof of concept based on the design as per my schematic  using both +5V and +3.3.V and so far I've had no issues. After a couple of changes as per Daniel's advice below, I will stick to my design.

Comment: I think you meant this question to someone else?

Comment: Sorry Andy yes it was for someone else. I thought I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Zigbee module manual, we find this:

```
Absolute Maximum Ratings:
Inputs: -0.3V to Vcc + 0.3V
```

http://www.telegesis.com/downloads/general/TG-ETRX35x-PM-010-100.pdf
(Page 14)

Meaning that the voltage on any input pin should not be above 3.6V in this design, since it is being powered from 3.3V.

This is violated on Pin 18, in the micro Tx to Zigbee Rx. You can improve the situation by adding something like a 10k resistor. This will limit the current that will flow through the Zigbee module's input pin protection diode, but since a max current rating for it is not given, you just have to guess at the resistor value.

Andy is right about your PIC not being suitable for less than 4.2V. If you look at parameter D001 on page 417 of the PIC datasheet, you can see that the LF version would work though:

```
PIC18LF2X80/4X80 2.0 — 5.5 V
PIC18F2X80/4X80 4.2 — 5.5 V
```

Looking back one page you can find your max speed:

```
FMAX = (16.36 MHz/V) (VDDAPPMIN – 2.0V) + 4 MHz
```

Where VDDAPPMIN might be 3.1V or so, to give you some margin.

Using the 3.3V PIC would definitely simplify your design, if you can deal with the IO to P1 and X1 being 3.3V as well.

---

As for the MCP1703, you need to estimate your average circuit current and determine whether the power dissipation is too high or not. There is a big section of the datasheet that gives a walkthrough of the math needed to estimate both power and thermal performance.

I would definitely recommend adding some unmasked, floating copper to the TAB pad of the regulator though, for dissipating heat.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed advice. Please accept my apologies if this sounds silly but just to confirm regarding my error on the line between my PIC Rx (pin 18) to my Zigbee module (pin 17) I will be hooking one end of my current-limiting resistor to this line and the other to ground right? Having gone through Andy's comments and page 417 of the PIC datasheet for the ideal operation range I will be sticking with supplying +5V to the board.

Comment: The (suggested) 10k resistor connects directly from pin 18 IC7 to pin 17 IC3.

We're making use of a hidden diode inside the Zigbee module-- the anode is connected to the pin, and the cathode is connected to +3.3. This is used to protect the internal circuitry from temporary overvoltages. You could also use a divider made of two resistors, one of them going to ground, to change 5v into 3.3v directly, if using the input protection diode bothers you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'd rather go ahead with the use of the suggested 10k resistor between the pins. I'll give it a go on my breadboard set up of the schematic before amending the schematic and board files.

Comment: The suggested 10 k resistor works as the voltage on the Zigbee Rx pin is no more greater than the recommended 3.6V. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add some info to the previous answers, we had a circuit operating a PIC18F2580 at 3.3V with a 10 MHz crystal and the 4x PLL enabled (thus 40 MHz clock). Usually, this configuration was working without problems. But we eventually noticed that when operating this way, the CAN bus was not communicating anymore starting from a temperature of around 35 °C. We eventually replaced the part with a PIC18LF2580 and a 20 MHz crystal (no PLL anymore), and the CAN problem disappeared...